# glVertexAttribPointer needed everytime glBindBuffer is called?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL (OpenGL ES 2.0 in particular), is glVertexAttribPointer required to be called each time a new VBO is bound?

For example:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexStruct), (void*)offsetof(vertexStruct,position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(vertexStruct), (void*)offsetof(vertexStruct,color);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)0);

// If vertexBuffer2 has the exact same attributes as vertexBuffer1
// is this legal or do the calls to glVertexAttribPointer (and glEnableVertexAttribArray)
// required again?

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer2);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)0);
```

I know that there are VAOs that address not having to call glVertexAttribPointer but I'm wondering if this is ok to do in OpenGL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you did this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer1);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertexStruct), (void*)offsetof(vertexStruct,position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_POSITION);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(vertexStruct), (void*)offsetof(vertexStruct,color);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)0);
```

Your code would work just fine. What all of the `gl*Pointer` calls do is look at what is stored in `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` *at the time the function is called*, and create an association between that buffer and that attribute. So the only way to change what buffer gets used for an attribute is to call `gl*Pointer`.